# SQL inserts slow - "pre populate with blank rows??"

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update, sql-insert, insert-update

I have an .exe that compares a vbTab delimited .txt file with an SQL table.

Updates to the table's existing records goes very fast. Inserts into the table for new records is quite slow.

As I'm new to SQL, I'm wondering if my idea is crazy talk:

I thought that maybe a solution would be to "pre populate" the database with 10,000 empty rows (minus the primary key) and somehow have this speed up the process?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The slow inserts could be due to page splits on the table. Can you show me the structure of the table you are inserting on? Forget about pre populating the table. Also you might have a very heavily indexed table this will also create a slow insert.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will be adding more details here shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward answer to your question as many things are unknown to us (DB configuration, HW, existing data etc.)

But you can try below things,

1. Try using DB export-import functionality

   Instead of fetching records from DB with an iterator and comparing them with a record from a file and then do insert of modification you can directly import those records into DB using upsert (update if present or insert if not) strategy. Believe me this works lot faster than previous.
2. If you have indexes on that table, while import or insert drop the current indexes on that table and do the operation. After operation re-apply those indexes again. Indexes slows down the performance of inserts.
3. If import strategy is not good for you (If you are doing with those records first before insertion) then probably go for stored procedure for modification and insert new rows after dropping indexes.

During this activity check for DB configuration as well. Use proper tuning for buffers, paging, locking.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great stuff! I will check out how the team has this table set up and let you know what specific things are going on

Comment: Thank you for this information, we decided to go with #2. As we haven't heard of this method yet, we are excited to check it out! I appreciate your help, you've been great!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Import utility with dropped indexes is worth trying

Comment: Yeah, we are going to check that out for sure! Is there any downside to doing the following? (A) Drop indexes (B) Insert records (C) Reapply Indexes ?? I was reading on Clustered indexes and wondering if this would cause fragmentation at all??

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question we may need more information.
How many rows does your table have?
I guess it may be a lack of  indexes.

Comment: Indexes are not used while insertion. And for your information, indexes kills insert performance.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will be adding more details here shortly